# Equi-existence of (co)products

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938094/existence-of-coproducts-and-products-in-category) question, does anyone know the *strongest* condition that ensures a category has sums if and only if it has products. What of other (co)limits?

Comment: "Weakest" implies the set of such conditions should be directed under implication, which is probably false. One nice condition that implies products and coproducts appear simultaneously is preadditivity.

Comment: Sure, you stated it in your question: "it has products iff it has coproducts". That's literally by definition the "weakest" condition.